# Glew Linking Problems in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, sdl, glew

I'm trying to link GLEW (with SDL and OpenGL - note, not SDL's implementation of OpenGL) in Qt Creator via a QMake file, though I'm not having much luck. No matter what I try, I seem to get the same string errors which deals with `conflicting declaration` problems stemming from a few `typedef`s. What I'd like to know is why this is happening, along with what can be done about it.

**Example**

```
/usr/include/SDL/SDL_opengl.h:4855: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, const GLfloat*)’
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:12201: error: ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, GLfloat*)’
```

Is this because I'm linking with SDL (seeing as how it has OpenGL support), or is there something else going on here?

**Qmake File**

```
QT += core

LIBS += -lSDL -lSDL_image -lopengl32 -lGLU -lGLEW
```

**stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once

/*************/
/* #includes */
/*************/

//GL / SDL
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>

//STD
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//Qt
#include <QListIterator>
#include <QMapIterator>
#include <QVector4D>
#include <QColor>

/********************/
/* Using Statements */
/********************/

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

using std::fstream;
```

**stdafx.cpp**

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
```

Comment: these are compilation errors - not linker erros

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: Why are you including SDL at all? Qt does everything SDL would do.

Comment: I'm building a Game Engine, something which Qt isn't quite meant for.

Comment: Actually, Qt can provide you with an OpenGL context just as SDL can. The actual engine part would be separate in both cases. If you're using Qt you might as well use its OpenGL capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to your problem is not to use one (either GLEW, or SDL_opengl), or at least do not include both `GL/glew.h` and `SDL/SDL_opengl.h` headers in any source or header file.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues before which we "solved" by defining `NO_SDL_GLEXT` before the inclusion of `<SDL/SDL_opengl.h>`, so:

```
#define NO_SDL_GLEXT
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
```

I say "solved", because it made the errors go away, but I never investigated possible side-effects or problems (we ended up moving away from SDL shortly after that and never really used it anymore). Perhaps worth a try...